# Cannot view Jenkins build information data in Hygieia build widget

Tags: jenkins, devops, hygieia

We are looking up to populate the build information data of Jenkins in Hygieia dashboard. As a part of this, we have installed :
All the necessary pre-requisites. (Java, Maven, NPM , etc)
Mongo DB - created users ,
Installed Hygieia core , API ( The test URL result of this API is successful with 200 status code) ,
Installed Hygiea UI and in the end We could able to view the sample Hygieia dashboard also.

After successful installation, we have installed Jenkins collector and mentioned the Jenkins URL, its API key , db username and password in the properties file.
After re-starting the Jenkins-collector, hygieia UI and API servers, in the Hygieia dashboard, we could able to create a dashboard and configured widget too. But in the build job section, even though we could see the list of our jenkins job in the list of dropdown, when we select a particular job and save the widget, **the jenkins data seems to be not populating and we are getting a message "data not found"** - I have restarted the server and application several points but landed up with no luck.

In the jenkins collector logs, all i can see is :

2020-10-30 02:21:45,041 [taskScheduler-1] INFO  c.c.d.collector.DefaultHudsonClient - Fetching jobs 0/304 pageSize 1000...
2020-10-30 02:21:55,355 [taskScheduler-1] INFO  c.c.d.collector.CollectorTask - Fetched jobs                    10s
**2020-10-30 02:21:55,362 [taskScheduler-1] INFO  c.c.d.collector.CollectorTask - New jobs                0        0s
2020-10-30 02:21:56,340 [taskScheduler-1] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.bson.BsonSerializationException: Payload document size of is larger than maximum of 16777216**

Is this something related to MongoDB error or error in my configuration ? But i think if the configuration is wrong, why can i see all the list of jenkins jobs in Configure widget -> Build job section.
Any pointers or suggestions woild be much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We have managed to fix this error by using Push based collector from Jenkins to Hygieia instead of Pull base collector.

This push based collector pushes the data in Hygieia dashboard on every build upon configuring and testing the Hygieia hostname on Jenkins Global settings.

Comment: Hi @Decoder, 

We are unable to get the deployment details in product dashboard. But, we are able to see the Jenkins Deployment details in teams dashboard.
Is there any deployment collector ? If Yes, please give the download link
Thank you